# boost error while make rcssbase

Tags: c++, boost, robocup

i am trying to install rcssbase. while i "./configure" no problem occurs. but when i want to "make" this error comes:

loader.cpp: In static member function ‘static boost::filesystem3::path rcss::lib::Loader::stripDirName(const boost::filesystem3::path&)’:
loader.cpp:158:38: error: conversion from ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ requested

```
boost::filesystem::path
Loader::stripDirName( const boost::filesystem::path & filename )
{
    std::string rval = filename.leaf(); //this is the 158th line
    return rval;
}
```

Comment: after the instruction you must install another lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is related to libboost library, it better to use apt package manager for these apps that have so many dependencies .

you can add rcssserver repository to your repository in ubuntu

do these steps if your ubuntu version is <= 12.10 :

1) you can find the repository here : **https://launchpad.net/~gnurubuntu/+archive/rubuntu**

2) now the addresses that you find in the previous step to your ***/etc/sources.list*** file

3) now type `sudo apt-get update`

4) `sudo apt-get install rcssserver rcsslogplayer rcssmonitor`